# write php codes independent from template

Tags: php, templates

How can I write php codes independent from XHTML codes?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What are you doing, what techniques are you using, and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please elaborate your problem. I think I am able to understand your problem but I first need to know if I am thinking it right.

Comment: @pekka;
I think that my question clear enough. Im using php. Thats all

Comment: @Gaurav Sharma;
I have not any problem. I want advice from php gurus.

Comment: @jasmine your question is far from clear enough. I will not participate in this question in this condition.

Comment: ok pekka thanks for attention

Comment: There it is again. Really, I don't get it. Some low rep guy or gal comes to SO and asks a question that contains little to no information about the problem at hand. When kindly asked to clearify by someone actually *willing to help*, s/he will start to argue instead of providing more info. I've noticed this behavior several times now. Actually @jasmine, you could get much better answers, if you'd just be more clear about the problem, instead of telling us you want advice from "PHP Gurus" (whoever those may be) and refusing Pekka's friendly request.

Comment: 1- client side: xhtml- css
2- server side: php (not any frame work)
3- editor: eclips
4- problem : not any problem
5- Asking for help : any "good" resource or book.

That it :D

And gordon, some comments not very "friendly", I can see this .
thanks for attention

Comment: @jasmine the *not very friendly* comments have been taken care of by the community very quickly. I find it somewhat funny to complain about the unfriendly comments though, when your own comments don't seem to be too friendly either. It may just be me, but I perceive your comments as quite snotty. Moreover, the clearification you gave in the former comment still adds nothing to the question. If you don't have a problem, then what are you asking for? Good book for what? Language barrier aside, what's so difficult to put up a proper question, even in non-perfect english?

Comment: Yes, not friendly comments flaged and you dont see them now.
Its my question:
"writting php codes independent from template"


I will delete my question!!! Its very clear. Why you depressed me???
If my question is bad, feel free to damn it.

Comment: @jasmine ok, this is going nowhere and since you accepted an answer already, I guess you got the answer you were looking for. Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can study MVC structure.

Also have a look at [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Comment: Don't use Smarty. PHP is a fine templating language in it's own right. Why complicate it with another language on top of it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a PHP framework like cakePHP or Zend.

or create a custom solution and use template engine like [Smarty](http://smarty.net) for separating your code logic with design.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can separate logic from markup only with pure php, which is in fact a good templating language.

Before doing MVC, an approach was to put code on separate classes, getting results needed on top of page and only using variables to echo or loop them inside html markup. You can use the same pattern to included portions of xhtml, the separations of concerns is then moved to pure code files and classes design.

But as we are 2010 I definitely vote for using MVC, even for very small project, with or without a framework.

Comment: so what can be a serious alternative for website development ?

Comment: actually I find the approach you gave for before 2010 fully sufficient for small sites. What for would I need MVC when all I want to do is put up some (semi-)static pages and maybe a contact form? Separating C and V is a definitely a must, but that can be done in the same file and it's not always necessary to separate the M from the VC when your app barely contains any domain logic. Don't get me wrong, MVC is great and helps tackle complexity *when that is needed*, but when not, it's just bloat. It's just a matter of when to use which pattern.

Comment: ok, I think i'm too regular with MVC frameworks to think to this, but it may be a good approach as long as no database interaction is required.